# Vue.js dynamic imports

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, localization, es6-modules

Vue.js fellow developers,

I have a data set I'm storing in a .js file (*reason for using .js right now, is so I can preserve comments, etc*).

My directory structure looks as such:

```
├── data
│   ├── cards
│   │   ├── en.json
│   │   ├── fr.json
```

Somewhere in my app, I import that data and then declare it in my data.

```
import Cards from '@/data/cards/en.js';
data() {
  return {
    cards: Cards, // < Imported.
    ...
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish, is import that locale file based off of a language property set in my .env file `VUE_APP_LANG=en`.

What's the best way to go about this? Although I know it's not possible, it would be nice to import using string literals (e.g. `` import Cards from `@/data/cards/${curLang}.js`; ``).

I'm aware, that yes I can just group the two in a `Cards.js` file and have my array return an object, one for each locale but it's not as clean. My preference is to keep locale data each in it's own dedicated file.

Yes, I'm also aware of available plugins like `vue-i18n`, unfortunately it has shortcomings specific to my project needs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import)

```js
import(`@/data/cards/${curLang}.js`).then(module => {
  // do something with the translations
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant those lang files be json?
If those lang files have js functions in there, aside from data, then maybe its better to implement it as a factory function.

But if its just pure data, why not json?
Or if it really needs to be on js, why not just attach it globally or have it on vuex? So you dont need to import it.

And since you will be adding it to the current Vue component instance as data, probably just have it on vuex and add it as computed property.

You can alway check the current VUE_APP_LANG set on your .env using

```
process.env(VUE_APP_LANG)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
const card = () => import "./Card"
```

Comment: Please include a short description of _how_ / _why_ this resolves the asker's question.

Comment: You cannot do that `An import declaration can only be used at the top level of a module.Vetur(1473)`